# Embedding XMP Metadata into PDF

Tags: pdf, metadata, xmp

I need to add XMP Metadata into PDF files and the googles searches I've done hasn't been of great help. I'm looking for a tool similar to PDFTK which I can run via command line or through a script to add the XMP Metadata into PDF.

Please help me out if there's a way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that comfortably using the open source XMP Toolkit which has a PDF plugin.Download the toolkit from http://www.adobe.com/devnet/xmp.html.
Follow these steps.

1. Download the Toolkit
2. Follow the build instructions in 
   XMPProgrammersGuide.pdf - section 4 Using the XMP  Toolkit SDK.
3. In the same Programmers guide go through the "Walkthrough 2: Modifying XMP"  Build the ModifyingXMP.cpp sample, debug and see how it works.
4. Modify the sample as per your needs and use it as a command line
   tool.

If you face any problems ask for help in the SDK forum http://forums.adobe.com/community/design_development/xmp_sdk .

Answer (score 0):

The adobe SDK has source code for modifying XMP in images files. The PDF file is far more complicated. Last time when I checked it does not contain utility to modify PDF files.

You can use PDFLeo to extract and embed XMP to PDF files:

http://www.morovia.com/manuals/pdfleo-1/PDF-Overview.php#XMP-Metadata-Processing